# How remove extra javascript

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

Can anybody know about how i can remove extra javascript code from my site genuinebatteries.com

So how i can remove javascript codes from site as SEO point of view it's too bad for us..

Example

Please see in your end if we can make this internal JAVASCRIPT codes to be EXTERNAL FILE through HTTP request or remove it completely

```
Here is the INTERNAL JAVASCRIPT for CURRENCY CONVERTER that can be found on the site.


<scripttype="text/javascript">

  function get_url_var(url_var) {

    varurlHalves = String(document.location).toLowerCase().split('?');
    varurlVarValue = '';

    if (urlHalves[1]) {
           varurlVars = urlHalves[1].split('&');

           for (var i = 0; i <= (urlVars.length); i++) {
                   if (urlVars[i]) {
                           varurlVarPair = urlVars[i].split('=');

                           if (urlVarPair[0] &&urlVarPair[0] == url_var.toLowerCase()) {
                                  urlVarValue = urlVarPair[1];
                           }
                   }
           }
    }

    return urlVarValue;
    } 


$(document).ready(function () {



    $('#bussoc-paypal-express').live('click', function() {
           $.ajax({
                   url: 'https://www.genuinebatteries.com/payment/bussoc_paypal_express/init',
                   type: 'get',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(json) {
                           $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

                           if (json['error']) {

                                  if (json['error']) {
                                          $('#notification').html('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error'] + '<imgsrc="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                                          $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
                                  }
                           }       

if (json['redirect']) {
                                  location = json['redirect'];
                           }       
                   }
           });            
    });     




    if (get_url_var('route') == 'checkout/cart') {
           varobj = $('#content h1');
        if (obj != undefined ) {
           $(obj).append('<div style="float:right; margin-top:6px;"><a id="bussoc-paypal-express" ><imgsrc="catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" alt="Paypal Express" /></a></div>');
        }
    }
           });
```

thanks for reply
i did it according to your instructions but it does not work, following is the code which i need to move in external file from internal file of currency converter module see this code of tpl file

javascript code was at end and then i move it to another file and reference it like that please see....

```
<div class="box">
```

```
<div class="box-currency">

    <div class="c-amount">

        <?php echo $text_amount; ?>

        <input style="text-align:right" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo $currency_value; ?>" name="currency_value"/>

    </div>

    <div class="c-from">

        <?php echo $text_from; ?><br />

        <select  style="max-width:160px" name="currency_from">

                    <?php foreach($currencies as $currency){ ?>

                        <option <?php echo ($currency['currency_code'] == $currency_from) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="<?php echo $currency['currency_code']; ?>"><?php echo $currency['currency_name'].'('.$currency['country_code'].')';?></option>

                    <?php } ?>

                </select>

    </div>

    <div class="c-to">

        <?php echo $text_to;?><br />

        <select style="max-width:160px" name="currency_to">

                    <?php foreach($currencies as $currency){ ?>

                        <option <?php echo ($currency['currency_code'] == $currency_to) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="<?php echo $currency['currency_code']; ?>"><?php echo $currency['currency_name'].'('.$currency['country_code'].')';?></option>

                    <?php } ?>

                </select>

    </div><br />

    <div style="text-align:center" class="converter">

    <div id="c-loadding"></div>

    <a class="button" id="goconverter" ><span><?php echo $text_converter;?></span></a>

    </div><br />

    <div class="c-results">

     <p class="prices"> <?php echo $currency_value.$currency_from.' = '.$currencyconverter['amount'].$currency_to; ?></p>

     <p style="font-size:10px"><?php echo $text_rate.$currencyconverter['date'].' '.$currencyconverter['time']; ?></p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript code is following which i grab from above file at the bottom

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
```

$('a#goconverter').bind('click',function(){

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',

    url: 'index.php?route=module/currencyconverter',

    data: 'currency_value=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'currency_value\']').val()) + '&currency_from=' + encodeURIComponent($('select[name=\'currency_from\']').val()) + '&currency_to=' + encodeURIComponent($('select[name=\'currency_to\']').val()),

    dataType: 'json',

    beforeSend: function() {

    $('#c-loadding').html('<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" id="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');

},

    success:function(json){

        if(json.error)

        {

            $('.c-results').html('<p style="color:red">'+json.error+'</p>');

            $('#c-loadding').html('');

        }

        if(json.currencyconverter)

        {

            var html = '';

            html += '<p class="prices">';

            html += json.currency_value + json.currency_from;

            html += ' = '+ json.currencyconverter['amount'] +'';

            html += json.currency_to;

            html += '</p>';

            html += '<p style="font-size:10px">';

            html += '<?php echo $text_rate; ?>';

            html += json.currencyconverter['date']+json.currencyconverter['time'];

            html += '</p>';

            $('.c-results').html(html);

            $('#c-loadding').html('');

        }

    }

})
```

});

//-->

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that that's bad for SEO?

Comment: it's not understand well by google. so is there a way to remove or can move out to extra file please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that crawlers just *ignore* `<script>` tags. Now, if you're fetching the actual content via AJAX through javascript, then it could be a problem, though that's not a problem in your case.

Comment: In the case of Google, their spider actually [executes JS and will load external JavaScript files](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/does-loading-and-executing-external-javascript-have-influence-on-seo).  Adding JavaScript to the page (internally or externally) will have no effect on SEO (at least for Google or any other decent web crawler).

Comment: You do know that the code will be executed by the browser either way, right? You're simply wasting time trying to "fix" this.

Answer (score 4):

Put the JavaScript in a separate file on the webserver and then include it with a script tag such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Though I highly doubt this will have any SEO impact.

Comment: please see above update code which i need to move in external file

Comment: It pains me that there is need for an answer like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your question is, but I think:

1. Take all your script (not the html tags) and put it into another file with a .js extension.
2. Put a link like this into your page:

> `<script type="text/javascript" src="MyNewFile.js"></script>`

This should allow your page to work in the same way and allows your users to potentially cache this file when serving the page.

Comment: i did it , but when i click on convert button (100usd to Eur) it's not working, nothing happen . even i copy all javascript code to separate file as js and call as you mention...what next?

Comment: Are you sure you have the link right to the JS file?  (Can usually use something like firebug/chrome inspector to confirm this).

Comment: please see above update code which i need to move in external file. tpl and js file codes above and file path mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want this inline with your html, make a new file `currencyConverter.js` place all the content in this file and add a reference to it in your html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/currencyConverter.js"></script>
```

It's a good idea to have all your javascripts in a common place, i.e `js` directory under the web root directory

Comment: thanks if i face another porblem i'll conatact you thanks really

Comment: i did it , but when i click on convert button (100usd to Eur) it's not working, nothing happen . even i copy all javascript code to separate file as js and call as you mention...what next?

Comment: Was this working before? A little debugging might help. If you using Firefox try to enable [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see if any errors occur in your page

Comment: please see above update code which i need to move in external file. tpl and js file codes mentioned above..see please

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem and post the problematic area. The error might be on the client side code or even or the server side code. I just can't follow the flow of a whole application

Comment: i did it' wow i just remove first line and last line of javascript code